# Ошибка при работе с php namespace

Tags: php, namespace

```
<?php

namespace Controller;

class ActionController {
}
```

Объявляю namespace Controller:

```
namespace Model\forms\create;
use Controller\ActionController;

class Create {
}
```

Использую namespace `Controller\ActionController`.

Когда пытаюсь запустить в браузере выдает:

> Uncaught Error: Class 'Controller\ActionController\ActionController'
>   not found in ...

Где моя ошибка?

Comment: что-то вы не договариваете.  убедитесь что `use` у вас в файле написан именно так как тут. данный код никаких ошибок не выдает.

Comment: Вообще `Controller\ActionController\ActionController` может получиться если вы написали `new ActionController\ActionController()` например. Но так как ваш код слишком секретный чтобы нам показывать, то бог его знает что там неправильно.

Answer (score -1):

Вас не смущает что вы создали неймспейс Controller а использовать хотите Controller\ActionController ?

```
namespace Model\forms\create;
use Controller;

class Create {
   ActionController::method()
}
```